# How to convert any type of text into Toggle Case by using javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, toggle, uppercase, lowercase

How i can convert my upper case, lower case , sentence case into toggle case by using the javascript function? Can any body elaborate how it can be done?

Comment: Why do you mean by _'toggle case'_? Can you put an example?

Comment: Please add an example(input and output) and the code which you have tried for better explanation of the issue..

Comment: sir in toggle case every first character of each word is in lowercase and other remaining characters are in uppercase. This is for every word in a sentence, For example this is toggle case:- tOGGLE cASE

Comment: Toggle case:- tOGGLE cASE

Comment: Upper Case:- UPPER CASE

Comment: Lower Case:- lower case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you see if this function helps your case

```
function toggleCase(str) {
  return str.toUpperCase().split(' ').map(function(word) {
    return (word.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + word.slice(1));
  }).join(' ');
}
toggleCase("this sentence is in lower case which is to be converted to toggle case");
```

Output : "tHIS sENTENCE iS iN lOWER cASE wHICH iS tO bE cONVERTED tO tOGGLE cASE"

Comment: Respected sir, I am grateful to you for the kind help. GOD bless you.

Comment: Thanks.. Happy Learning

Answer (score 0):

```js
// For this question, Leading lowercase and remaining uppercase chars
const toggleStr = str =>
      str
        .split(" ")
        .map(word => word[0].toLowerCase() + word.slice(1).toUpperCase())
        .join(" ");

// Generic toggle each char based on current char
function toggleChars(str) {
  let updated = "";
  const [upp_start, upp_end, low_start, low_end] = "AZaz"
    .split("")
    .map(x => x.charCodeAt(0));

  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    const charCode = str[i].charCodeAt(0);
    let diff = 0;
    if (charCode >= upp_start && charCode <= upp_end) {
      // change uppercase to lowercase
      diff = low_end - upp_end;
    } else if (charCode >= low_start && charCode <= low_end) {
      // change lowercase to uppercase
      diff = upp_end - low_end;
    }
    updated = updated + String.fromCharCode(charCode + diff);
  }
  return updated;
}

console.log(toggleStr("stack overflow is great"));

console.log(toggleChars("gReAt sTorY"));
```

Answer (score 0):

previous code working fine but in the case of multiple paragraphs very first word of each paragraph not change so for example

```
lOREM iPSUM dOLOR sIT aMET, cONSECTETUER aDIPISCING eLIT.

LOREM iPSUM dOLOR sIT aMET, cONSECTETUER aDIPISCING eLIT.

LOREM iPSUM dOLOR sIT aMET, cONSECTETUER aDIPISCING eLIT.

LOREM iPSUM dOLOR sIT aMET, cONSECTETUER aDIPISCING eLIT.
```

So I modify the code for this issue hopefully it's helpful for others

```
function togglecase(str){
        var str_ar=str.split('\n');
        var output='';
        $(str_ar).each(function(k,v){
            var outText=v.toUpperCase().split(' ').map(function(word) {
                return (word.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + word.slice(1));
            }).join(' ');
            output+=outText+"\n";
        });
        return output;
    }
```

The output is good and working fine on each paragraph

OUTPUT:

```
lOREM iPSUM dOLOR sIT aMET, cONSECTETUER aDIPISCING eLIT.

lOREM iPSUM dOLOR sIT aMET, cONSECTETUER aDIPISCING eLIT.

lOREM iPSUM dOLOR sIT aMET, cONSECTETUER aDIPISCING eLIT.

lOREM iPSUM dOLOR sIT aMET, cONSECTETUER aDIPISCING eLIT.
```